# efficiently create dask.array from a dask.Series of lists

Tags: python, numpy, dask, dask-delayed

What is the most efficient way to create a `dask.array` from a dask.Series of list?
The series consists of 5 million lists 300 of elements.
It is currently divide into  500 partitions.
Currently I am trying:

```
pt = [delayed(np.array)(y)
      for y in
      [delayed(list)(x)
       for x in series.to_delayed()]]
da = delayed(dask.array.concatenate)(pt, axis=1)
da = dask.array.from_delayed(da, (vec.size.compute(), 300), dtype=float)
```

The idea is  to convert each partition into a numpy array and stitch 
those together into a `dask.array`.
This code is taking forever to run though.
A numpy array can be built from this data quite quickly from this data sequentially as long as there is enough RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are on the right track using dask.delayed.  However calling `list` on the series is probably not ideal.  I would create a function that converts one of your series into a numpy array and then go through delayed with that.

```
def convert_series_to_array(pandas_series):  # make this as fast as you can
    ...
    return numpy_array

L = dask_series.to_delayed()
L = [delayed(convert_series_to_array)(x) for x in L]
arrays = [da.from_delayed(x, shape=(np.nan, 300), dtype=...) for x in L]
x = da.concatenate(arrays, axis=0)
```

Also, regarding this line:

```
da = delayed(dask.array.concatenate)(pt, axis=1)
```

You should never call delayed on a dask function.  They are already lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this with some dummy data.  Building on @MRocklin's answer (and molding more after my specific use case), let's say that your vectors are actually list of ints instead of floats and the list is stored as a string.  We take the series, transform it, and store it in a zarr array file.

```
# create dummy data
vectors = [ np.random.randint(low=0,high=100,size=300).tolist() for _ in range(1000) ]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['vector'] = vectors
df['vector'] = df['vector'].map(lambda x:f"{x}")
df['foo'] = 'bar'
ddf = dd.from_pandas( df, npartitions=100 )

# transform series data to numpy array
def convert_series_to_array( series ):  # make this as fast as you can
    series_ = [ast.literal_eval( i ) for i in series]
    return np.stack(series_, axis=0)

L = ddf['vector'].to_delayed()
L = [delayed(convert_series_to_array)(x) for x in L]
arrays = [da.from_delayed(x, shape=(np.nan, 300), dtype=np.int64) for x in L]
x = da.concatenate(arrays, axis=0)

# store result into a zarr array
x.compute_chunk_sizes().to_zarr( 'toy_dataset.zarr', '/home/user/Documents/', overwrite=True )
```